# Переменное количество параметров у функции, как передать дальше?

Tags: php

```
<?php

class SampleClass {
    function invoke () {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $name = array_shift($args);
        if (method_exists($this, $name)) {
            # Место которое хотелось-бы оптимизировать:
            switch (count($args)) {
                case 0:
                    return $this->$name();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    return $this->$name($args[0]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return $this->$name($args[0],$args[1]);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    function method0 () {
        return "method0 ()" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    function method1 ($arg1) {
        return "method1 ($arg1)" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    function method2 ($arg1, $arg2) {
        return "method2 ($arg1, $arg2)" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$s = new SampleClass;
echo $s->invoke('method0');
echo $s->invoke('method1','ArgNo1');
echo $s->invoke('method2','ArgNo1','ArgNo2');
```

**UPDATE**

Правильное решение выглядит так:

```
return call_user_func_array(array($this,$name), $args);
```

Comment: Интересный вопрос, дабавлю-ка я его в избранное)

Comment: да, я тоже)

Comment: Посыпаю голову пеплом, можно оказывается так сделать:

    return call_user_func_array(array($this,$name), $args);

Comment: А если передавать 1 параметр-объект.В свойства записываем передаваемые параметры....

Comment: Такое возможно когда код пишется с нуля. Но для повторного использования существующего кода проще использовать тот подход который я привел. Подробнее см. Мемоизация/Memoization

Answer (score 1):

А кто мешает сделать так:

```
function invoke () {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $name = array_shift($args);
    if (method_exists($this, $name)) {
        return $this->$name($args);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну тогда мне придется методы переписывать что-бы они принимали массив с параметрами в качестве единственного параметра, а этого не хотелось-бы делать по нескольким причинам:

   * они могут наследоваться из других классов.
   * придется переписывать существующий код.

Просто в других языках програмирования подобная вещь делается легко и непринужденно, а в PHP...

Answer (score 0):

Собственно весь вопрос состоял про функцию: [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). Ниже приведен код (несколько больше чем в вопросе, но и более подробный)

```
<?php

class SampleClass {
    var $name = "NoName";

    function __construct ($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    function invoke () {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $func_name = array_shift($args);
        $func = is_array($func_name)
            ? $func_name
            : function_exists($func_name)
                ? $func_name
                : array($this, $func_name)
        ;
        if (is_callable($func, FALSE)) {
            return call_user_func_array($func, $args);
        }
        else {
        throw new Exception("No $func_name found");
        }
    }
    function method0 () {
        return $this->name . " > method0 ()";
    }
    function method1 ($arg1) {
        return $this->name . " > method1 ($arg1)";
    }
    function method2 ($arg1, $arg2) {
        return $this->name . " > method2 ($arg1, $arg2)";
    }
}

$s = new SampleClass('o_O');
try {
    echo $s->invoke('method0'), PHP_EOL;
    echo $s->invoke('method1','ArgNo1'), PHP_EOL;
    echo $s->invoke('method2','ArgNo1','ArgNo2'), PHP_EOL;
    echo $s->invoke('xxxxxxx'), PHP_EOL;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "$e", PHP_EOL;
}
```